# What are complex numbers, actually?

Tags: complex-numbers

What are complex numbers, actually? You can prove $1=-1$ and a complex cosine function can have value greater than $1$ and so on, there are many unexpected results when we use complex numbers. So, what are they actually? Do, they have any physical meaning or are they just a method in mathematics to manipulate numbers?

Comment: How can you prove $1=-1$?

Comment: Here the link-https://brilliant.org/assessment/techniques-trainer/proof-that-1-1-and-1-3/ .Actually the proof has a small mistake(you can easily identify it) but however complex numbers give weird results in some cases.

Comment: The point of that question is that it is wrong. Even using complex numbers, there is no way to prove $1=-1$, nor are there other contradictory results.

Answer (score -1):

A complex number is a number that has both Real and Imaginary Components, It is the the form $$a+bi$$ where $i$ is defined as $$i=\sqrt{-1}$$

Comment: If you have never heard of "complex numbers", the term "real/imaginary component" is useless. Also, $i:=\sqrt{-1}$ is useless if you have not defined the square root function for negative numbers, except if this is just a notational trick, but this is not what you wrote.